# Looping through SharedPreferences using Map

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have the code shown below, where I'm trying to loop through some stored values and add it as text to a TextView. My problem is that the third object does not get printed, while the first two does. Right now, I have no idea why the third object is not retrieved, and any help to find it out is appreciated.

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(MySecondActivity.PREFS_NAME, 0);
int var1, var2, var3;
var1 = settings.getInt("First key", MySecondActivity.var1);
var2 = settings.getInt("Second key", MySecondActivity.var2);
var3 = settings.getInt("Third key", MySecondActivity.var3);

Map<String, ?> map = settings.getAll();
for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    TextViewStats.append(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue().toString() + "\n");
}
```

Comment: show how you store the values into preferences

Comment: Ah...this comment made me see my mistake. I have forgotten to save th last value: editor.putInt("First key", var1);
        editor.putInt("Second key", var2); was all I had

Comment: Glad that helped you, consider to post an answer that help other with the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to crgarridos I managed to see my mistake. It was actually quite a silly one. I had just forgotten to store a value into  SharedPreferences. With this code in MySecondActivity, it is working:

```
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putInt("First key", var1);
    editor.putInt("Second key", var2);
    editor.putInt("Third key", var3); //<- Hehe...

    // Commit the edits!
    editor.commit();
```